# SQL Server turn off or handle backslash remove newline

Tags: sql-server, backslash

As described here [(Backslash) (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/sql-server-utilities-statements-backslash) you can insert `\` as end of line to better reading and by `INSERT INTO` the text gets removed.

How to handle this if I do not want this behavior?

Example:

```
INSERT INTO [table] ([column]) VALUES ('---
:path c:\test\
:param another_string')
```

Current result at the moment in this column:

```
---
:path c:\test\:param another_string
```

Of course I can modify my SQL statement in this example, but it shows data that may come from any input.

Comment: well when working with SSMS you could at least manually work-around it. It's actually a real issue if the SQL is programatically constructed. Atm my only idea would be to pre-process the data to persist by replacing any trailing backslashes on any line end with Char(92). But that seems overkill to work-around a convenience feature of MSSQL.

Comment: Can you provide a more complete example? You didn't describe where/how exactly you are entering these commands and what do you want them to do.

Comment: Old post but faces the problem exactly: https://spin.atomicobject.com/2008/03/18/trailing-backslash-problem-and-fix-for-rails-and-sqlserver-2005/

Answer (score 0):

The backslash will only continue the current line if it's immediately followed by a newline. Under normal circumstances, this should not be an issue except when you forget the closing quote.

If you are accessing SQL programmatically, use prepared statements to ensure you can safely pass any strings without breaking the SQL.

Comment: This is a work around I already did, too. That would result into programmatically search and replace new-line on a very low level in a adapter (e.g. Free-TDS).

Comment: If your data can come from any input you don't have control over, it can always contain special characters such as quote, backslash or `--`. If you just copy-paste it without escaping, it can break your SQL (not to mention SQL injection attacks). This is one of the main reasons for using prepared statements. If you are using SSMS, you have to do it yourself. You can also try the @'xxx' syntax.

Comment: You missing the topic. Of course any current available framework checks stuff like this to prevent injections, etc. But you can simple produce this behavior creating a stored procedure that gets any text to insert. The point is how to make sure that this `\`problem can be handle on SQL server directly as it is a feature that not really anyone I know needs but cause lots of trouble.

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO [table] ([column]) VALUES (N'---
:path c:\test\' + CHAR(13) + '
:param another_string')
```

Comment: This is a work around I already did, too. That would result into programmatically search and replace new-line on a very low level in a adapter (e.g. Free-TDS).

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300837/what-comment-should-i-add-to-code-only-answers